# From the point of view of the caller, how is calling an asynchronous method any different than calling a synchronous method?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

What I don't understand is the following snippet [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456401.aspx):

> Note that the method is now marked with the new async keyword; this is
>   simply an indicator to the compiler that lets it know that in the
>   context of this method, the keyword await is to be treated as a point
>   where the workflow returns control to its caller and picks up again
>   when the associated task is finished.

How is that any different than how non-`async` methods work?

If I do

```
int x; 
x = SomeNormalFunctionThatReturnsAnInt(); 
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

or

```
int x; 
Task<int> task = SomeAsyncFunctionThatReturnsAnInt();
x = await task; 
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

then ***from the perspective of the caller***, the order of execution is the exact same: an `int` named `x` is defined, a function that returns an `int` is run, and when that funcion is done running, its return value is set to `x`, which is then written to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from the perspective of the caller, the order of execution is the exact same

Yes and no.

If you `await` all tasks as soon as they are returned to you, then **yes**, that method in isolation is seeing the same "order of execution". This is actually the entire *point* of `async`/`await` - it allows writing most asynchronous code in a way that is very natural and similar to equivalent synchronous code.

However, the caller *must* be aware that it has to be asynchronous. That is, the caller generally uses `await`, which means that it must be `async`. There are some added twists that come in with asynchronous code. One example: if this is executed on a UI thread, then synchronous code knows that nothing else can execute on the UI thread between `SomeNormalFunctionThatReturnsAnInt` and `Console.WriteLine`; however, asynchronous code uses `await`, so it must accept that anything else can execute on the UI thread between `SomeAsyncFunctionThatReturnsAnInt` and `Console.WriteLine`. So, looking at it from that context, it's **not the exact same**; asynchronous methods may have their "order of execution" paused while other code runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't waiting the result of the function x could be not initialized. But here you wait for it so there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have some read on the async and sync to see what happens in performance level ,

in your example the result is not different as you are saying the method to wait in line of await but lets have a look at the following code snippet

```
class Program {
  private static string result;

  static void Main() {
    SaySomething();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }

  static async Task<string> SaySomething() {
    await Task.Delay(5);
    result = "Hello world!";
    return “Something”;
  }
}
```

can you try to calculate the output, the result is nothing, why ?

with the await we let the main task continue as we wait 5 milliseconds before returning result, have a look at

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: Task.Delay takes milliseconds not seconds, if you wanted to wait 5 seconds that would be Task.Delay(5000)